# How to recursively divide a square into different parts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, recursion

I have a `data.frame` containing the coordinates of a square.

```
square = data.frame(xmin = c(0),
                xmax = c(1),
                ymin = c(0),
                ymax = c(1))
```

Using `ggplot2`, I can plot the square:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(square, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
        geom_rect() +
        coord_fixed()
```

which produces:

[image]

Now, I want to have a function, that takes a `data.frame` containing the four coordinates of a square and divides this square into 4 rectangles, giving the first 3 rectangles a separate colour and leaving the last one uncoloured:

[image]

Then, I want this function to divide the last/uncoloured rectangle into 4 squares, giving the first 3 squares a separate colours (but the ordering of the colours should match with the ones in rectangles) and leaving the last square uncoloured:

[image]

This would be the end of the first iteration. But, I want to use this function iteratively and recursively.

For example, if the iteration number is defined to be 2, I want this function to take the coordinates of the last/uncoloured square and repeat the processes explained above.

So, if we repeat this whole function 2 times, we would end up with similar figures:

[image]

[image]

I want to repeat this process many times. Also, I would prefer this recursive function to produce a `data.frame` so that I can use `ggplot2` to visualise it later.

What I have tried so far is a lot of hardcoding the coordinates to make the rectangles and squares. Obviously it is a big problem as I want to repeat this process many times. It would take significant amount of time to manually hardcode the plot.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problem(s) did you encounter / where did you get stuck?

Comment: Even after the edit, this still doesn't read like a useful Stack Overflow question. There's not really a single question here; it more reads like you are assigning an unpaid programming task. Are you changing the values in the original data.frame? Or are you trying to create a custom ggplot geom? How did you make the image you included in the post? Questions can get downvotes if they show no research effort or are unlikely to be of any use to others.

Comment: To be fair, it is quite tricky to show an example when you don't have an idea on how to plot such figure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code initiates a first dataframe with the row rule and a column rule.
The second part of the code applies the same formula splitting each time each part of the square.

```
### Initiating magnificent colors
Colors <- c("#00a5da", "#2bec00", "#6b00ec", "#fff3b9")

### Initiating first dataframe
dfCols <- data.frame(xmin = seq(0, 0.75, 0.25),
                     xmax = seq(0.25, 1, 0.25),
                     ymin = rep(0, 4),
                     ymax = rep(1, 4))
dfRows <- data.frame(xmin = rep(0.75, 4),
                     xmax = rep(1, 4),
                     ymin = seq(0, 0.75, 0.25),
                     ymax = seq(0.25, 1, 0.25))
dfBoth <- rbind(dfCols, dfRows)

### Looping
for(i in 1:4){
dfCols <- data.frame(xmin = dfCols$xmin[4] + dfRows$ymax[1]*0:3/4, 
                         xmax = dfCols$xmin[4] + dfRows$ymax[1]*1:4/4, 
                         ymin = rep(dfRows$ymin[1], 4), 
                         ymax = rep(dfRows$ymax[1], 4))
dfRows <- data.frame(xmin = rep(dfCols$xmin[4], 4), 
                         xmax = rep(dfCols$xmax[4], 4), 
                         ymin = dfRows$ymax[1] - dfRows$ymax[1]*4:1/4,
                         ymax = dfRows$ymax[1] - dfRows$ymax[1]*3:0/4)
dfBoth <- rbind(dfBoth, dfCols, dfRows)
}

### Plotting
ggplot(dfBoth, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
  geom_rect() + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=dfBoth$xmin, xmax=dfBoth$xmax, ymin=dfBoth$ymin, ymax=dfBoth$ymax, fill=rep(Colors, nrow(dfBoth)/4), alpha=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Concerning color order, I guess, this would work: `fill=rep(c(Colors, rev(Colors)), nrow(dfBoth)/2)` if you have an even number of splitting